# MySQL Valores de un INT

Tags: sql

estoy haciendo unas tareas de MySQL y me ha entrado una duda..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado probando y el numero maximo que se puede agregar es 2,147,483,647 en ambos...

Entonces mi duda es.. para que sirve darle longitud de 2 y 6 ..

He buscado información en internet pero solo me encuentro con la longitud de bits de cada tipo smallint, mediumint, bigint e int...

Gracias por su tiempo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El número dentro del paréntesis no indica el tamaño en bytes, siguen siendo 4 bytes en ambos casos.

int(M)

M indica el ancho máximo que retornara el visualizador, no todos los clientes MySQL admiten este valor.

por ejemplo:

```
create table miTabla ( unidades int(4) unsigned zerofill not null default 0 );

insert into miTabla (unidades) values (123),(456),(1234);

select * from miTabla;
```

Resultado:

0123

0456

1234

te retornará siempre un entero con el número de dígitos que le asignes, si no lo tiene lo rellena con ceros.

Fuente: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: Muchas gracias!