# Duda sql int(n)

Tags: sql

¿Qué significa la siguiente sentencia sql que está entre paréntesis: `int(4)`?

¿Ese "4" que significa porque he introducido valores con más de 4 dígitos y los almacena?

Comment: ¿Cuál sentencia SQL?

Comment: @Ruiz Enrique Creo que eso ya lo contestaron en esta pregunta:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155476/mysql-valores-de-un-int